# Std. error of accuracy on 3-class problem

Tags: distributions, standard-error, bernoulli-distribution

I want to find the std. error of accuracy on a 3-class problem, where the following is true. Number of observations is `N=40000`, number of classes is `m=3` and accuracy is `a=0.63`.

For a similar 2-class problem with `a=0.80` I can simply use the Bernoulli distribution, where the std. error is `sigma(a) = sqrt(a(1-a)/N)=0.002`. How do I do it for the 3-class problem?

Comment: Could you tell us specifically what the number $a$ means?  How is it measured?

Comment: It is the percentage of correctly assigned labels in a classification problem. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you're only tracking the proportions of correctly and incorrectly assigned labels, it seems the number of classes would be irrelevant.  Usually, though, you would want to keep a table of the types of each error you can make (six with three classes), because their rates can vary a lot.

Comment: Ah, yes of course! I was thinking of the std. error of proportions being dependent on the number of classes, but as long as the split is simply into 2 classes, then the std. error calculation will be the same. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're refering to a confusion matrix  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix). Sadly, I don't have room for that.

Comment: Yes, that would be a confusion matrix.  Could you explain what you mean by not having "room" for nine numbers?

Comment: I'm comparing 5 classifiers. Even if I were to organize it nicely, it would still take up a lot of space in my report :)

Comment: Feel free to write an answer based on your comment.